# Nginx load content to different URL

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I need to load content of admin.example.com/admin/login to admin.example.com. Site is running in Symfony.

Here is my block.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  admin.example.com
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html;

location / {  
       return 301 http://admin.example.com/admin/login;
     } 
}
```

It shows error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 0):

add the folder name you're using like:
root /var/www/html/yourFolderName;

Answer (score 0):

1. You can edit your Symfony controller and routing.yml to use both address:

routing.yml

Add new route:

`homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: ApplicationBundle:Default:login }`

Your old route:

`login:
    path:     /admin/login
    defaults: { _controller: ApplicationBundle:Default:login }`

2. You can use Mod rewrite to substract the addres:

   Mod rewrite:

`RewriteRule / /admin/login [L]`

3. Edit your ngix redirect to be also [L]

> "[L] is a flag that means that if this rule matches, then no other 
>   rule matching will be performed for this page."